# SharePoint Add-in: Client Id and secret for US Gov tenancy

Tags: sharepoint-addin, client-object-model, provider-hosted-app

We have a SharePoint (SP) provider hosted add-in that works in normal SP sites in commercial cloud. However, for tenancies where Azure AD is in US Gov cloud, we are not able to create the client context even though the app gets installed in SP site.

If we create the Client Id and Secret using appregnew.aspx then we are able to create context (/_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx). However, these will work only in the specific tenancy from where it is generated.

From where can we generate Client Ids that can work with US Gov tenancies? We are creating IDs in [seller dashboard](https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/office/overview) but it does not give any option for normal vs. US Gov Ids.

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: @windfly2006 Sadly no. Still waiting for some reasonable documentation on this topic.

Comment: Thanks Prakash. We end up adding the client id to the tenant through AppRegNew.aspx page for now.